# Python frequency of records while combining combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, permutation, frequency

I've started using python for a pet project as organizing this data was not possible in a program like excel. I hope you can give me some guidance on how to achieve the result I'm looking for. Please excuse my lack of python literacy.

I have the following code, which I have simplified by reducing the number of lists and the number of elements in those lists to make it easier to illustrate.

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

a = list(itertools.permutations([32,36,41],3))
b = list(itertools.permutations([36,32,41],3))
c = list(itertools.permutations([19,31,7],3))

fulllist = a+b+c

print(Counter(map(tuple, fulllist)))
```

which gives the following result:

```
Counter({(32, 36, 41): 2, (32, 41, 36): 2, (36, 32, 41): 2, (36, 41, 32): 2, (41, 32, 36): 2, (41, 36, 32): 2, (19, 31, 7): 1, (19, 7, 31): 1, (31, 19, 7): 1, (31, 7, 19): 1, (7, 19, 31): 1, (7, 31, 19): 1})
```

This is already quite good but not excatly what I need. Now that I have the first count of each list-combination generated by intertools, I don't care anymore about the order of each element inside of said list. So, the final result I would like to obtain is:

```
(32, 36, 41): 12 
(19, 31, 7): 6
```

And sorted, just like I have written above.
I feel I might be going in circles and perhaps there's a simpler way to get the result I'm looking for. In reality, my lists have 15 elements in them and I have around 50 of these lists to process.

I hope you can help me with this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So the real end result is the counts? Why not just calculate those counts, rather than generate the all those combinations?

Comment: `counts = {}`, then `key = tuple(sorted(inputlist))` and `count = math.factorial(len(inputlist))` and `counts[key] = counts.get(key, 0) + count`, where `inputlist is one of those three inputs. No need to generate any of the permutations at all.

Comment: Side note: the `map(tuple, ...))` is not needed, as all permutations are already tuples. You should really use `itertools.chain()` to combine the permutation iterators.

Comment: For the full 50 lists result, do you produce permutations of length 3, or length 15?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not counting permutations (in that case use @Martin's answer), and that was just used to create an example list, just sort to make it clear order does not matter:

```
>>>print(Counter(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in fulllist))
Counter({(32, 36, 41): 12, (7, 19, 31): 6})
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a *count* of possible permutations, then just *calculate* those numbers. That number is simply the factorial of the length of the input:

```
import math

permutationcount = math.factorial(len(inputlist))
```

If you are creating permutations that are *shorter* than `len(inputlist)` (say, 3 out of 20), then the formula is `n! / (n - k)!`:

```
n = len(inputlist)
k = 3
permutationcount = math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n - k)
```

Of course, when `k` is equal to `n`, then you divide by 0!, which is 1.

You can sort the input list, and turn it into a tuple, to create a key into a mapping:

```
from collections import Counter

def count_permutations(lists, k=None):
    counts = Counter()
    if k is None:
        k = len(lists[0])
    for l in lists:
        key = tuple(sorted(l))
        permutationcount = math.factorial(len(l)) // math.factorial(len(l) - k)
        counts[key] += permutationcount
    return counts
```

Demo:

```
>>> count_permutations(([32,36,41], [36,32,41], [19,31,7]), k=3)
Counter({(32, 36, 41): 12, (7, 19, 31): 6})
```

You don't really need to use a `Counter` here of course, but it may be convenient to use one anyway if you need the `.most_common()` method and don't want to look up how to sort a dictionary by value.

Answer (score -1):

```
c = Counter(map(tuple, fulllist))
l = [ {tuple(sorted(i[0])):i[1]} for i in c.items()]  

for e in l:
    print(e)  

{(32, 36, 41): 2}
{(32, 36, 41): 2}
{(32, 36, 41): 2}
{(32, 36, 41): 2}
{(32, 36, 41): 2}
{(32, 36, 41): 2}
{(7, 19, 31): 1}
{(7, 19, 31): 1}
{(7, 19, 31): 1}
{(7, 19, 31): 1}
{(7, 19, 31): 1}
{(7, 19, 31): 1}
```

Comment: How is this solving the OPs problem? Where are you collating the numbers into sorted sets?

Comment: @MartijnPieters. You are correct. I did not sort the tuples.